# Query takes long in Codeigniter than in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, debugging, codeigniter

I've got the following query, and in phpmyadmin it takes 0.055 seconds, but in CodeIgniter the exact same query takes more then 2 seconds. Anybody got an idea what the problem might be?

The query only gives about 25 results, so that shouldn't be any problem...

Here's the query

```
SELECT `Qty`, `Invt`, `ClassNr`, `SubPartCode`, `Description`, `DesignCode`, `Measure`, `Remark`, `PartMnem`
FROM (`loodvrij_receptuur` lr)
JOIN `loodvrij_artikel` la ON `la`.`PartCode` = `lr`.`SubPartCode`
WHERE `lr`.`PartCode` =  'M2430A'
ORDER BY `SubPartCode`, `Qty` desc
```

**EDIT**

This is the way I tried to execute the query in CodeIgniter

```
$this->db->query("SELECT `Qty`, `Invt`, `ClassNr`, `SubPartCode`, `Description`, `DesignCode`, `Measure`, `Remark`, `PartMnem`
                  FROM (`loodvrij_receptuur` lr)
                  JOIN `loodvrij_artikel` la ON `la`.`PartCode` = `lr`.`SubPartCode`
                  WHERE `lr`.`PartCode` =  'M2425B'
                  ORDER BY `SubPartCode`, `Qty` desc");
```

And

```
$this->db->select('Qty, Invt, ClassNr, SubPartCode, Description, DesignCode, Measure, Remark, PartMnem');
$this->db->from('loodvrij_receptuur lr');
$this->db->join('loodvrij_artikel la', 'la.PartCode = lr.SubPartCode');
$this->db->where('lr.PartCode', 'M2425B');
$this->db->order_by('SubPartCode');
$this->db->order_by('Qty', 'desc');
```

Comment: IIRC Views are faster than tables when dealing with `JOIN`. Also is there a reason why everythings escaped with ` and `

Comment: CodeIgniter adds the ` automatically.

Comment: post the php code where you execute the query

Comment: if youre running the query from a particuliarly large controller that uses a particuliarly large model to run that query that could be a bit expensive to instantiate.  Especially depending on if youre instantiating or doing a bunch of stuff in the controllers constructor.

Comment: @JohnB The controller or model are nothing special. And other queries that fire after or before take just 0.003 seconds or something.

Comment: i would benchmark the whole query using the benchmark class and see if that really takes 2 seconds. enable the profile and mark the beggining and the end of the query and see the results. maybe the query isn't the problem. just do $this->benchmark->mark('start_query'); $this->model->getData(); $this->benchmark->mark('end_query');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you said the query gives only 25 results? does the table have only 25 results or more?
Phpmyadmin automaticaly adds a limit clause, so it gives you only 20 something results. if your tables has more than 25 records, that maybe the culprit, because i don't see a limit clause in your ci query.

Comment: Okay... that seems to be the problem. One table has 80.000 records, other one has 20.000 records. The query only gives 25 results, but when I add a random `LIMIT 30` or something (like phpmyadmin does) the query suddenly is fast. That raises another question, why does the limit that is higher than the total results, make the query faster?

Comment: probably because it doesn't go throgh all the records. mysql stops when the first x records have been found based on your query paramteres and then return the results

Comment: Yeah but you would think that if it hasn't found 30 records yet, it would continue searching the rest of the tables and not stop. Don't really understand why it would make it faster. Happy it does, but don't understand why ;)

Comment: i mysql guru maybe able to answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that PHPMyAdmin accesses your database from a more direct route.

Comment: It's just a normal MAMP installation, default phpmyadmin and a simple website. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @Crinsane it shouldn't. both scripts should execute the query in the same time. Is phpmyadmin on the same server as the codeigniter application?

Comment: @Vlad Jep, same server, have it on localhost